# How to correctly inject EntityManager into JAX-WS web service?

Tags: java, jpa, jax-ws

I'm trying to implement a JAX-WS web service which has an endpoint that returns data from the configured data source. I managed to create the service and the client, but I can't access the database because I get Null Pointer Exceptions when I try to use the injected EntityManager.
Here is my service:

```
@WebService(serviceName="ViewDocuments")
public class ViewDocumentService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "HibernateJPA")
    private EntityManager em;

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    @Produces("application/json")
    @WebMethod(operationName="getDocuments")
    public List<File> getDocuments(@WebParam(name = "name") String filename) {
        if(filename == null)
            return em.createQuery("FROM File").getResultList();
        else return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my WebServiceClient:

```
@WebServiceClient(name="ViewDocuments", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/lab8/ViewDocuments?wsdl")
public class ViewDocumentClient extends Service {

    protected ViewDocumentClient(URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlDocumentLocation, serviceName);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "DocumentPort")
    public ViewDocumentService getDocumentPort() {
        return new ViewDocumentService();
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the function here:

```
public class MainDocumentClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL wsdlUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/lab8/ViewDocuments?wsdl");
        QName serviceName = new QName("http://webservices/", "ViewDocuments");
        ViewDocumentClient service = new ViewDocumentClient(wsdlUrl, serviceName);
        ViewDocumentService viewDocumentService = service.getDocumentPort();
        System.out.println(viewDocumentService.sayHello());
        System.out.println(viewDocumentService.getDocuments(null));
    }
}
```

This is my persistence.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="HibernateJPA" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:/Postgres-Source8</jta-data-source>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="HibernateJPAForTests" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lab8" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="<password>" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The `sayHello()` method works fine. I also tried to use an `EntityManagerFactory`, to instantiate my `Repository` by hand, to add the `@Stateless` annotation, but nothing seems to work. I just can't query my database.
After lots of research, I still can't seem to understand how to properly inject the EntityManager. Can someone explain this to me, please?

I am using Wildfly21.0.0.

Comment: you deploy as war file to Wildfly right?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Then you need to go to wildfly subsystem and configure the data source before you deploy your file. It is possible that the datasource is not defined in wildfly to be used

Comment: I already did that, I needed the JNDI for the persistence.xml file. My project successfully performs CRUD operations from Managed Beans. The only problem I have is with the Web Service.

Comment: please share the persistence.xml

Comment: You can inject the `EntityManager` in other beans in the same WAR using the `PersistenceContext` anotation?

Comment: Yes, I managed to do that in my ```@Stateless``` repositories. After that, I could inject the repositories in managed beans and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@Stateless` to `ViewDocumentService`?

Comment: yes, no success unfortunatelly

Comment: Try to add an empty `beans.xml` file in the WAR `WEB-INF` directory to activate CDI.